# Adding a button in Galleria

Tags: html, galleria

I would like to add a button to Galleria, allowing the visitor to be directed to another url page. i am working in Dreamweaver in code mode.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a button, quite minimal. CSS3.

```
button.galleria {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 #E3E3E3;
        border: 1px solid #BBBBBB;
        border-radius: 3px 3px 3px 3px;
        box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #F6F6F6 inset;
        color: #333333;
        font: bold 12px/1 "helvetica neue",helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
        padding: 8px 0 9px;
        text-align: center;
        text-shadow: 0 1px 0 #FFFFFF;
        width: 150px;
    }

HTML

<a href="yourlink.html" alt="galleria button"><button class="galleria">Galleria</button></a>
```

Comment: Yes, this does give me a button... however, it is placed behind the images. I tried changing the z index, but it still places the button behind the main image and is only visible for a split second, when the page first loads.